# formatting table ascii python

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to add a space after the second column without adding it to the first column , but if I tried to add it in a dirty way like `'| '.join` my cells become a mess , but how can I have the output desire ? I also tried with `rjust(3)` and it doesnt work

```
_id = ['1', '2', '3','4']
transport = ['http','tcp','https','dns']
agent = ['10.10.1.1','10.10.1.2','10.10.1.3','10.10.1.4']
username = ['DESKTOP-123\\user','root','user','user']
os = ['windows/amd64','linux/amd64','windows/amd64','linux/amd64']
seen = ['2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08']
titles = ['ID', 'Transport', 'Agent', 'Username','Operating System','Last Seen']
data = [titles] + list(zip(_id, transport, agent, username,os,seen))

def os():
    print("\t")
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(18) for x in d)
        print(line)
        if i == 0:
            sep = '-' * 18 + '+'
            line = ''.join(sep for x in d)
            print(line)
    print("\t")
```

I want to have an output adding a space after the pipe line execpt the first column

```
|1 | 2 | 3 |
+--+---+---+
|4 | 5 | 6 |
|7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Comment: Looks like the tabulate package (https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) would make your life easier.

Comment: yeah , but I did this way , and I am almost to finish , but that space is making a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first line definition inside for enumerate data to:

```
line = f'{str(d[0]).ljust(18)}| {"| ".join(str(x).ljust(17) for x in d if d.index(x) > 0)}'
```

It would be something like:

```
_id = ['1', '2', '3','4']
transport = ['http','tcp','https','dns']
agent = ['10.10.1.1','10.10.1.2','10.10.1.3','10.10.1.4']
username = ['DESKTOP-123\\user','root','user','user']
os = ['windows/amd64','linux/amd64','windows/amd64','linux/amd64']
seen = ['2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08','2019-08-31 13:10:08']
titles = ['ID', 'Transport', 'Agent', 'Username','Operating System','Last Seen']
data = [titles] + list(zip(_id, transport, agent, username,os,seen))

def os():
    print("\t")
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        line = f'{str(d[0]).ljust(18)}| {"| ".join(str(x).ljust(17) for x in d if d.index(x) > 0)}'
        print(line)
        if i == 0:
            sep = '-' * 18 + '+'
            line = ''.join(sep for x in d)
            print(line)
    print("\t")
```

Result:

```
ID                | Transport        | Agent            | Username         | Operating System | Last Seen        
------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
1                 | http             | 10.10.1.1        | DESKTOP-123\user | windows/amd64    | 2019-08-31 13:10:08
2                 | tcp              | 10.10.1.2        | root             | linux/amd64      | 2019-08-31 13:10:08
3                 | https            | 10.10.1.3        | user             | windows/amd64    | 2019-08-31 13:10:08
4                 | dns              | 10.10.1.4        | user             | linux/amd64      | 2019-08-31 13:10:08
```